# Sorting flights by departure dates

Tags: c

These are the flights below:

```
AA43 DFW DTW 2016-01-06 11:00
AA43 DFW DTW 2016-01-17 11:00
AA44 SEA JFK 2015-02-05 7:45
AA197 ORD BOS 2012-03-12 11:50 
AA1 JFK LAX 2016-07-02 9:00
OO7435 DTW PLN 2016-11-22 21:55
F9612 DEN MIA 2014-12-19 22:15
DL801 GEG MSP 2016-08-31 9:00
DL1087 ATL DAB 2016-04-10 12:05
DL828 IAH SLC 2012-06-02 7:45
```

Now imagine if all those flights were inside a text file.
how would you sort them by departure dates?
When I mean "departure date" I mean sort them from "yyyy-mm-dd hr:min".

When I tried to sort it, it would just sort everything of the flights instead of the just by departure dates. If there were no airline flights but just departure dates it would sort perfectly.

Here is what it would look like in code for what I was saying earlier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;
    int i, j;
    int line = 0;
    char temp[128], outputFile[15], airLine[256];
    char **strData = NULL;

    printf("Enter input file name:");
    scanf("%s", airLine);

    fp1 = fopen(airLine,"r");
    if (!fp1)
    {
       return 1;
    }

    sprintf(outputFile, "sun");
    fp2 = fopen(outputFile, "w");

    while(fgets(temp, 128, fp1))
    {
        if(strchr(temp, '\n'))
        {
            temp[strlen(temp-1)] = '\0';
            strData = (char**)realloc(strData, sizeof(char**)*(line+1));
            strData[line] = (char*)calloc(128, sizeof(char));
            strcpy(strData[line], temp);
            line++;
        }
    }
    for(i= 0; i < (line - 1); ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < ( line - i - 1); ++j)
        {
            if(strcmp(strData[j], strData[j+1]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, strData[j]);
                strcpy(strData[j], strData[j+1]);
                strcpy(strData[j+1], temp);
            }
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < line; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp2,"%s\n",strData[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < line; i++)
    {
        free(strData[i]);
    }
    free(strData);
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

How would you be able to sort the flights listed above by departure dates <yyyy-mm-dd hr:min>?

Comment: Instead of `strcmp(strData[j], strData[j+1])` call `my_date_compare(strData[j], strData[j+1])` and write `my_date_compare()`.  Or are you looking for someone to provide that function?

Comment: Those look like flights, not airlines.

Comment: yeah you right with flight

Comment: There is another question on StackOverflow dealing with the ACARS database for flight information which you may find has a wealth of information pertaining to your question. A simple search of "C struct ACARS airline" should turn it up.

Answer (score 2):

It will require some effort.

1. Define structure for your flight data

   ```
   struct flight {
     char flight_no[10];
     char takeoff[4];
     char landing[4];
     // you can convert string to tm using
     // strptime (take a look at time.h)
     struct tm *date_and_time;
   };
   ```
2. Create table of elements by storing pointers to the structure
3. Create function that can compare elements by date (see `man qsort`)

   ```
   int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)
   ```

   Function that does comparison, takes two arguments (pointed by `void *`). All we have to do (inside it) is to cast `void *` to the pointer of the type we are dealing with and compare values.

   ```
   int
   compare_doubles (const void *a, const void *b)
   {
     const double *da = (const double *) a;
     const double *db = (const double *) b;

     if(*da > *db) {
       return 1;
     } else if(*da < *db) {
       return -1;
     } else {
       return 0;
     }
   }
   ```

   source: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Comparison-Functions.html

   Note this part of docs

   > Your comparison function should return a value the way strcmp does:
   >   negative if the first argument is “less” than the second, zero if they
   >   are “equal”, and positive if the first argument is “greater”.
4. Sort elements using `qsort`

   ```
   man qsort
   ```

Comment: (suggestion) `"Create function that can compare elements by date (see man qsort)"` -- that is usually what causes new C programmers eyes to roll back in their heads trying to figure out what the heck the man page is talking about regarding a "compare" function that takes two `const void*` pointers. May be worth finding a link on SO, or suggesting a search for `"qsort compare function"` to help fill in the terse information provided by `man 3 qsort`.